# can we use the same filters to create cascade parameters and individual parameters in SSRS?

Tags: sql-server, reporting-services

I am creating a report which contains 3 parameters COUNTRY, STATE, and CITY. I have already created a cascade parameterized report which means the CITY result is based on the STATE result and the STATE result is based on the COUNTRY result. But what I want now is, in the same report and parameters if I just choose only COUNTRY or only STATE or only CITY, I want results as well. It should not give me any errors. That means if I only choose country and run the report it should show the result and the same with STATE and CITY. On the other hand, cascade parameters should also be active. Is it possible? If yes what will be the process and if not what would be the best option? The page will be used by multiple users throughout the website. Do I need to work on the code or the SSRS report or both?

Comment: As far as I know, cascading parameters only work in one direction, meaning you can't draw STATE values by "@CountryID "and by "@CityID". You may have better luck pulling those parameters from another UI where you have more control of user interactions.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. Appreciate it.

Comment: I mean to say; I want results if I only put COUNTRY, STATE, or CITY Name only as well. That means if I put only STATE I need all the results without filtering COUNTRY or CITY. All the results based on STATE should show based on the STATE.

Comment: @Kyoshi - You test this by adding a default parameter value for say City while leaving the other parameter defaults null.

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to do this easily (I think)...

You already have Country -> State -> City setup and I'm assuming the query for the available values will be something like...

```
SELECT State from myTable WHERE Country IN(@Country)
```

... and so on.

I'm also assuming that your final dataset query, the one that actually gets the report data have a `WHERE` clause that filters on `City`. e.g.

```
SELECT * FROM myMainTable WHERE City in (@City)
```

So, all you should need to do is to set the default parameters to the same dataset query as the available values.

When the report runs, all Countries will be selected, which means all states will be available/selected and therefore all cities will be available/selected.

There is also another, more complicated method which means the user chooses what to filter on first and then makes selections which in turn populate the next drop down but I think it's probably overkill. If this sounds of interest though, let me know and I'll dig out the answer I wrote a while back for somebody else.